# Долго выполняется COUNT(*) и выборка по условию. PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Имеется интернет-магазин с данным набором функций: поиск по тексту, сортировка, фильтры (чекбоксы), интервал цен, пагинация, количество найденных результатов.

Есть таблица на 300 тыс. записей. Таблица имеет вот такую структуру:

```
id (integer), status (integer), price (numeric)
```

Имеется индекс:

`CREATE INDEX market_index ON table USING btree (status, price) WHERE (status = ANY (ARRAY[2, 6])) AND price IS NOT NULL`

Анализ запроса COUNT(*):

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE status IN(2, 6) AND price IS NOT NULL`

```
Aggregate  (cost=3751.03..3751.04 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=101.936..101.936 rows=1 loops=1)

  -> Index Only Scan using market_index on table (cost=0.42..3631.61 rows=47768 width=0) (actual time=0.079..91.923 rows=114813 loops=1)

        Index Cond: ((status = ANY ('{2,6}'::integer[])) AND (price IS NOT NULL))

        Heap Fetches: 86792

Planning time: 1.217 ms
Execution time: 102.053 ms
```

Анализ запроса выборки:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE status IN(2, 6) AND price IS NOT NULL ORDER BY price DESC`

```
Sort  (cost=10238.83..10357.28 rows=47381 width=46) (actual time=105.422..118.449 rows=115602 loops=1)

  Sort Key: price DESC

  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 19329kB

  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table (cost=2572.96..6559.22 rows=47381 width=46) (actual time=22.602..49.464 rows=115602 loops=1)

      Recheck Cond: ((status = ANY ('{2,6}'::integer[])) AND (price IS NOT NULL))

      Heap Blocks: exact=3389

      -> Bitmap Index Scan on market_index  (cost=0.00..2561.11 rows=47381 width=0) (actual time=22.124..22.124 rows=120400 loops=1)

      Index Cond: ((status = ANY ('{2,6}'::integer[])) AND (price IS NOT NULL))

Planning time: 0.539 ms
Execution time: 122.337 ms
```

Вроде бы все неплохо выглядит, но проблема в том что данная таблица очень часто изменяется и читается.

Изменяется в основном поле `status` на отличное от 2 и 6. Количество изменений - минимум 2 млн изменений отдельных записей в сутки.

Количество чтений колеблется от 10 до 50 в секунду (возможно больше). По мере нарастания количества чтений, замечается увеличение времени на выполнение запросов выше, хотя у сервера еще есть достаточно ресурсов для работы. Даже не доходя до "час-пик" сервер базы данных загружается по CPU до 100%. В этот момент задержки на дисках не обнаружил.

Условие `status IN(2, 6) AND price IS NOT NULL` является базовым для всех расширенных запросов по магазину. Тесты проводились именно по нему, расширенные запросы не использовались (поиск по тексту и т.д)

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема? Возможно ли что при обновлении записи блокируется индекс и тем самым замедляет чтение (Concurrent index не помог)?
Кэши не помогут, т.к вариаций запросов много и данные очень часто меяются.

Конфигурация сервера:

PostgreSQL 9.5

64 GB оперативной памяти (DDR4)

SSD диск (SOFT RAID)

Intel Xeon E5 E5-1650v3

PS. DDos атака исключена.

Comment: Count там всегда долгий. Ведь надо пройтись по всем записям и сосчитать их. Об этом разработчики честно говорят. А если данные меняются, то так ли уж важно, чтобы они были точными на определённый момент времени? Ведь через пару наносекунд они изменятся.Позже, раньше count был равен 100500 какая разница? Пока подсчитывается новое количество показывайте старое. Никто и не заметит подвоха.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Первый запрос с count

Похоже, explain вы сделали в момент низкой пишущей нагрузки на табличку или вовсе не на боевой копии.

У вас в explain значится [`Index Only Scan`](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans). Одно из важнейших условий для этого - `Visibility Map` сказал, что все строки доступны для всех транзакций и видимость строки проверять не требуется. Под интенсивной пишущей нагрузкой такого не будет. А если `visibility map` не сказал, что страница доступна всем транзакциям - значит её надо читать и проверять для каждой строки `xmin` и `xmax` - id транзакции, когда эта версия строки была добавлена и когда удалена.

Потому что это `MVCC`, у каждой строки может быть одновременно много различающихся копий, видимых в разных транзакциях. В индексе будут ссылки на все версии строк и нет информации о видимости строки. Добавлять информацию о версии строки в индекс разработчики не хотят, т.к. это сделает плохо сразу всем - версия строки в индексе потребует 16 байт места на каждую запись (xmin, xmax, cmin, cmax по 4 байта каждый, ничего не забыл?). Раздуть индекс по какому-нибудь bigint в 3 раза и почти ничего не дать взамен?

### Второй запрос с сортировкой по price

Postgresql согласился, что обойти весь partial индекс ему будет дешевле seqscan'а. Но индекс у вас построен по `(status, price)`. Поэтому отсортировать price индексом невозможно.

Поэтому postgresql прочитал весь индекс, построил список страничек, в которых есть подходящие для запроса данные (`Bitmap Index Scan`), а затем пошёл их читать и сортировать.

Для этого запроса индекс нужен

```
CREATE INDEX market_index ON table USING btree (price) WHERE (status = ANY (ARRAY[2, 6])) AND price IS NOT NULL
```

Надо смотреть другие запросы. Сдаётся мне, что они тоже от этого индекса могут получить только грубое первичное условие, а остальные 120 тысяч строк фильтровать, сортировать и всячески обрабатывать только силами CPU.

Поставьте [`pg_stat_statements`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/pgstatstatements.html) и спустя некоторое время посмотрите на топ запросов по утилизации CPU.

> Возможно ли что при обновлении записи блокируется индекс и тем самым замедляет чтение (Concurrent index не помог)?

Нет, невозможно. Страница индекса защищена системным локом на момент обновления, но этот лок снимается сразу после обновления странички памяти.

Индексы всегда рассчитаны на конкурентный доступ. `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY` относится именно к созданию индекса. Без указания CONCURRENTLY процесс создание индекса заблокирует изменение таблицы.

Читающие транзакции вообще чем-нибудь заблокировать сложно. Пишущие транзакции читающих не блокируют никогда - в этом и суть MVCC, за что приходится платить свою цену.

Comment: Сделал индекс как вы написали. Время выполнения уменьшилось на 10-20 мс. А вместо Bitmap Heap Scan и Bitmap Index Scan выполняется одна операция - Index Scan Backward. Какой плюс будет от этого решения? И запрос COUNT с этим индексом стал использовать Seq Scan, и время выполнения увеличилось на те же 10-20 мс

Comment: Та же таблица с 800 тыс. записями не стала использовать Index Scan Backward, а продолжила работать с Bitmap Heap Scan и Bitmap Index Scan на новом индексе.

Comment: index scan - значит сортировка результата не требуется вовсе. У вас почему-то лимита в запросе нет - что, все 120к записей на пользователя идут? С лимитом это будет top-N по индексу. Запрос, который решил дальше использовать bitmap - это какой запрос? Seq scan немного более странно. Может, analyze не сделали? Или данных по индексу надо вытягивать много относительно всего размера таблички.

Comment: Запрос, который дальше использует bitmap - это запрос с сортировкой. На 300 тыс. записях работает с Index Scan Backward, а на 800 тыс. записях с Bitmap Heap Scan и Bitmap Index Scan (как и было раньше). С лимитом запросы используют всегда Index Scan Backward.

Comment: Посмотрю как будет работать в бою, по результатам отпишусь.

Comment: Да, с этим решением лучше работает.